# End Powershell Job at specific time

Tags: powershell

apologies if this is really simple, but I'm very new to Powershell and still finding my way.

So, I'm trying to collect some data on processor and ram usage and then write it to a file. I want the script to run for a day, write to file then start again the next day.

The actual data collection is done as a job

```
$datacollector = Start-Job {
$totalRam = (Get-CimInstance Win32_PhysicalMemory | Measure-Object -Property capacity -Sum).Sum
while($true) {
    $date = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    $cpuTime = (Get-Counter '\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time').CounterSamples.CookedValue
    $availMem = (Get-Counter '\Memory\Available MBytes').CounterSamples.CookedValue
    $date + ' > CPU: ' + $cpuTime.ToString("#,0.000") + '%, Avail. Mem.: ' + 
    $availMem.ToString("N0") + 'MB (' + (104857600 * $availMem / $totalRam).ToString("#,0.0") + '%)'
    Start-Sleep -s 15
}} -Name datacollector
```

Then I set the amount of time to run it for

```
Start-Sleep -s 600
```

End the job

```
Stop-Job datacollector
```

And write the data to file

```
Get-Job datacollector | Wait-Job | Receive-Job | Out-File C:\output.txt
```

How can I set this job to stop at a specific time, instead of using the Start-Sleep command? I'm sure it's something simple, but I just can't see it.

Comment: this is FAR better done with task scheduler. PoSh is not good at running for long periods of time - it tends to simply vanish after "some number of hours".

Comment: Performance Monitor already has settings for logging interval, start and end times. Why invent the wheel again?

Comment: I know performance monitor can do this, but I'm looking for text output, with metrics I can easily manipulate to use in other scripts or platforms.

Comment: Performance Monitor supports text log format. And `relog` is available as built-in tool too.